# Identify and count array duplicates

Tags: arrays, swift2

I have the following array:

```
var newOrderItems = [Order]()
```

that holds Order type elements:

```
let order = Order(item: itemName, quantity: 1)
newOrderItems.append(order!)
```

At some point newOrderItems holds:

```
[
Order("item1", 1),
Order("item1", 1),
Order("item2", 1),
Order("item2", 1),
Order("item3", 1),
Order("item1", 1)
]
```

I need to identify and count duplicate Order array elements so that I form a string message such as:

"You have ordered 3 x item1, 2 x item2, 1 x item3".

Is there a simple way for this? My solution(s) either add way too much overhead (i.e nested loops), or too much complexity (i.e. unique `NSCountedSet`) for something that I expect to be trivial.

Comment: You should use a dictionary not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with a swift `dictionary` to manage orders like :

```
var newOrderItems = [Order: Int]()

if let order = Order(item: itemName, quantity: 1) {
            if newOrderItems[order] == nil {
               newOrderItems[order] = 1
            } else {
               newOrderItems[order]+=1
            }
}
```

And you can print details like :

```
var str = "You have ordered "
for order in newOrderItems.keys {
   str += "\(newOrderItems[order]) x \(order.item),"
}
print(str)
```

Hopefully it will help!

Comment: That would require Order to conform to protocol Hashable

Answer (score 0):

When you're originally appending the objects to the array, why not increase the counter there, rather than going through after, in order to save time?

Comment: I'd need multiple counters since different types of order items can increase / decrease infinitely (theoretically).

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
var str = "You have ordered "

for object in newOrderItems {
    let itemInstancesFound = newOrderItems!.filter({ $0["item"] as! String == object["item"] as! String }).count

    str += "\(itemInstancesFound) x \(object["item"] as! String),"
}
```

this assumes quantity is always 1 (as showed in my initial Q).